# How to set color mTitles Array in that API demo? 

Tags: android

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List6.html

In the above link , how toset color to mTitles string.

Comment: Your question is not clearly understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like in the getview function

```
TextView title = (TextView)sv.getChildAt(0);
title.setBackgroundColor(Coor.RED);
```